# Pass oracle object type to java stored procedure

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

Is is possible to pass oracle object type to java stored procedure. Here's what i have so far.

Java stored procedure:

```
create or replace and compile java source named Example as
import java.sql.SQLData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.SQLInput;
import java.sql.SQLOutput;

public class Example {
    
    public static void test(ExObj obj) {
        System.out.println(obj.client);
    }
    
    public static class ExObj implements SQLData {

        public String client = "";

        public String sql_type = "EXAMPLE_OBJECT";

        public ExObj(String client, String sql_type) {
            this.client = client;

            this.sql_type = sql_type;
        }

        /* IMPLEMENTS SQLData */

        public void setSqlType(String sqlType) {
            sql_type = sqlType;
        }

        public void writeSQL(SQLOutput stream) throws SQLException {
            stream.writeString(this.client);
        }

        public String getSQLTypeName() {
            return sql_type;
        }

        public void readSQL(SQLInput stream, String sqlTypeName) throws SQLException {
            sql_type = sqlTypeName;

            this.client = stream.readString();
        }

    }
}
```

Oracle procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE example(ex_obj in example_object)
AS LANGUAGE JAVA
NAME 'Example.test(java.sql.Struct)';
```

Oracle object type:

```
create or replace type example_object as object(
  client varchar2(40)
)
```

Script to call procedure:

```
declare
  l_output DBMS_OUTPUT.chararr;
  l_lines  INTEGER := 1000;
  
  l_obj example_object;
begin
  DBMS_OUTPUT.enable(1000000);
  DBMS_JAVA.set_output(1000000);
  
  l_obj := example_object('client');
  example(l_obj);

  DBMS_OUTPUT.get_lines(l_output, l_lines);

  FOR i IN 1 .. l_lines LOOP
    -- Do something with the line.
    -- Data in the collection - l_output(i)
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(l_output(i));
  END LOOP;
end;
```

When running script i get:

> ORA-29531: no method test in class Example
>
> ORA-06512: at "EXAMPLE", line 1
>
> ORA-06512: at line 17

I presume it's because oracle object_type doesn't map to java class correctly. Is there a way to do this and if so what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Should your `ExObj` constructor really have two arguments, when the SQL object only has one fieild? Why are you passing the `sqlType` into the constructor at all - should that be constant?

Comment: Yes it should be there, it should map java class to oracle object type. It works when i return java class to oracle, f.e. public static ExObj test1(String str) {return new ExObj(str);}. So i've presumed it should work when passing object type to java too.

Answer (score 1):

The below mentioned issue with your code can be the reason.

1) You must declare a varaible of `type` of your `object` so that you can use it. You cannot directly use `object` as a `datatype`. See below :

Demo:

```
create or replace type example_object as object(
  client varchar2(40)
  );

 /

--Created a type of the object
create or replace type x is table of example_object;

/


 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE example(ex_obj in X)
    AS
  begin

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Example.test(java.sql.Struct');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Inside the Procedure');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (ex_obj(1).client);

    end;
  /

    DECLARE
       l_output   DBMS_OUTPUT.chararr;
       l_lines    INTEGER := 1000;

       l_obj      x := x();      

    BEGIN
       DBMS_OUTPUT.enable (1000000);
       --DBMS_JAVA.set_output (1000000);

       --You need to mention the position where the record will be saved in table.
       l_obj.extend(); 
       l_obj(1) := example_object('client1');

       example (l_obj);

       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_obj(1).client);

       DBMS_OUTPUT.get_lines (l_output, l_lines);

       FOR i IN 1 .. l_lines
       LOOP
          -- Do something with the line.
          -- Data in the collection - l_output(i)
          DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_output (i));
       END LOOP;
    END;
```

/

Comment: You're saying that i can only pass an Array to stored procedure?

Comment: No..  I am saying you need to create a type of of your object first and then use it as a datatype. I created a type of your Object as associative array and used it. I can use it as nested table as well but that would bring some additional thing to do in code for me

Comment: Could you update your answer with example how i need to change my procedure which calls java stored procedure? Do i need to use java.sql.Array as java argument then?

Comment: I already updated the code.. See the difference between your code and mine. Read inline comments . Not sure one Java part. But you can make changes on DB part and give a try

Comment: Yes, but procedure example, and java source named example must be updated with different arguments too, since now running the script i get wrong number of arguments in call to example. And i'm now entirely sure what argument type i need to use in java code, since in script we're now passing table of object, is it java.sql.Array?

Comment: So now your fisrt issue is resolved. From DB side argument passing to the proc is correct. Please change the java.sq.array and see if it works.

Comment: But argument passing is not correct, since in proc i have argument example_object, and i'm trying to pass ...table of example object index by... .

Comment: You can use nestd table approach then. It will be a table of your object. i just gave an example of both . Either should work in oracle..Not sure how it works in Java.. Google down.

Comment: Situation is the same with both associative array and nested table, since we're trying to pass table of example_object when procedure's argument is example_object. Oracle throws: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'EXAMPLE'

Comment: I see how this could work, you pass array, open connection in java and map an java array to oracle table of object type, however that's not exactly what i'm looking for. Since i'll always be invoking procedure with only one object. And i'm not eager to create connections to database from java. My question was, is it possible to pass oracle object type to java stored procedure as an argument. I'm looking for something more of a java code perspective or how to define java stored procedure call, with an argument being passed, my oracle object type.

Comment: I mentioned at the very first line, You cannot directly use your object as datatype. Atleast not in oracle. Also I dont think JAVA has anything which support this. You need to create a type of your object. This implictly means the same what you wanted to do. Once you create a object. its used to store something and thats the use of table as well